Why signing a transaction needs a RPC call
I am using web3.py to build and publish my transaction. Observing that the send_transaction()'s latency is quite high, I split the function call into a "sign" and "send raw", as stated in the document:
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_endpoint))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=my_ca, abi=my_contract_abi)
transaction = contract.functions.myFunction(arg0, ar1).build_transaction(
    {"from": my_sender.address, "gas": 10000000, "nonce": nonce, "chainId": chain_id}
)
signed = my_sender.sign_transaction(transaction)   # this trigger an RPC call
hex_bytes = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)

It seems that the sign_transaction() function call trigger a RPC call internally.
I cannot understand why signing a transaction using my private key will require a RPC call.

I'm not totally clear what type of object your my_sender is, but you can use w3.eth.accounts to sign locally. See example here: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction
